# Codeigniter - How to receive or send email using codeigniter from dynamic sender

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, web, gateway

Please help me to finish my email gateway using codeigniter

I have a problem, i want to receive an email from sender(any person) to my email and 
if I send with that code, the email is sent from me

But i want the email should be sent from person to my email

**Controller**

```
public function prosespengiriman()
    {
       $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
       $this->load->library('email');

       //konfigurasi email
       $config = array();
       $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
       $config['useragent'] = 'Codeigniter'; 
       $config['protocol']= "smtp";
       $config['mailtype']= "html";
       $config['smtp_host']= "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
       $config['smtp_port']= "465";
       $config['smtp_timeout']= "5";
       $config['smtp_user']= "myemail@gmail.com";              
       $config['smtp_pass']= "mypass";            
       $config['crlf']="\r\n";
       $config['newline']="\r\n";
       $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

       $this->email->initialize($config);

       $this->email->from($this->input->post('from'));
       $this->email->to('myemail@mail.com');
       $this->email->subject($this->input->post('subject'));
       $this->email->message($this->input->post('isi'));

       if($this->email->send()){
        echo "tutorial pengiriman email berhasil";
       }else{
        echo "tutorial pengiriman email gagal";
       }

      }
```

**There is a view->content_contact.php**

```
 <table>
   <?php echo form_open_multipart('email/prosespengiriman'); ?>
   <tbody>

    <tr>
     <td>Dari</td>
     <td><input type="email" name="from"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Subject / judul</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Isi Pesan</td>
     <td><textarea name="isi"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

     <td></td>
     <td><input type="submit" value="Kirim"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   <?php echo form_close();?>
  </table></body>
```

**And there is the Controller** :
[Email.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yXng.png)

Comment: I think your PHP is to _send_ an email (which you will then _receive_). Please add `Email.php` to the question using `code` markup (like you have to `content_contact.php`), and edit your question to give more detail about how it is currently failing.

Comment: @AjahnCharles i've edited it